# I want to add two columns in a dataframe with incremental values

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to add two columns in a dataframe, let say we have 50 rows in the dataframe, so my Column 1 values should be 1 to 50, and Column 2 values should be 51 to 100.

```
def insertId(new_df, str):
    df.insertId(0, str, range(1, 1 + len(df)))
    return df
```

The above function needs correction in order to meet my requirement, but unable to do so, as i am a beginner in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Create first `numpy array` and pass it to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = np.arange(1, 101).reshape(2,-1).T
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a','b'])

print(df1.head())

   a   b
0  1  51
1  2  52
2  3  53
3  4  54
4  5  55
```

Last add it to original DataFrame:

```
df = df.join(df1)
```

---

Solution with your function with [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) - is possible specify position of column `pos`, then column name `col` and last start number `start`:

```
#some Dataframe
a = np.arange(1, 101).reshape(2,-1).T
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a','b'])
print (df.head())
   a   b
0  1  51
1  2  52
2  3  53
3  4  54
4  5  55

def insertId(new_df, pos, col, start):
    new_df.insert(pos, col, range(start, len(new_df) + start))
    return new_df

#insert new column called s to DataFrame df in position 0 and values starts in 50
df = insertId(df, 0, 's', 50)
df = insertId(df, 2, 'new', 14)
print (df.head())

    s  a  new   b
0  50  1   14  51
1  51  2   15  52
2  52  3   16  53
3  53  4   17  54
4  54  5   18  55
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create sample data for initial dataframe.
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
>>> df
          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863

# Add new columns in sequential order.
n = len(df)
new_cols = ['a', 'b']  # Desired names for new columns.
new_col_count = len(new_cols)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(1, n * new_col_count + 1).reshape(n, new_col_count, order='F')
    columns=new_cols, 
    index=df.index)
>>> pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
          A         B         C  a   b
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  1   6
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278  2   7
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  3   8
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274  4   9
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  5  10
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leverage @Alexander's setup

**Setup**

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
df
          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
```

**Option 1**
We can produce another general solution by performing an outer addition with Numpy.  In my example below, I'll show an example using 5 additional columns that I specify with `m = 5`.  I use `string`'s `ascii_lowercase` to grab labels for the the extra columns.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as labels
import pandas as pd
impot numpy as np

n = len(df)
m = 5

df.assign(**dict(zip(
    labels[:m],
    np.add.outer(np.arange(m) * n, np.arange(n))
)))

          A         B         C  a  b   c   d   e
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  0  5  10  15  20
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278  1  6  11  16  21
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  2  7  12  17  22
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274  3  8  13  18  23
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  4  9  14  19  24
```

---

**Option 2**
I tend to show solutions with `pd.DataFrame.assign`.  But we could've accomplished the same thing with `pd.DataFrame.join`, possibly with more clarity.  In this case, I'm still using Numpy's outer addition, but I'm using the transpose of what I did in option 1 and construction a new dataframe and joining it with the original one.

```
n = len(df)
m = 5

df.join(pd.DataFrame(
    np.add.outer(np.arange(n), np.arange(m) * n),
    df.index, list('abcde')
))

          A         B         C  a  b   c   d   e
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  0  5  10  15  20
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278  1  6  11  16  21
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  2  7  12  17  22
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274  3  8  13  18  23
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  4  9  14  19  24
```